# How to create folder if not exists in upstart script

Tags: linux, service, background, upstart

This is my config file in /etc/init/

```
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on shutdown
# Automatically restart service
respawn
respawn limit 99 5
script
    mkdir /var/log/my_task
    <my task which log to /var/log/my_task>
end script
```

The problem is the service will try create folder every time.
How to run the command only if the folder is not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work for you:

```
   start on local-filesystems
   stop on runlevel [!2345]
   respawn limit 99 5
   script
   if [ ! -e /var/log/my_task ]; then
     /bin/mkdir  /var/log/my_task
   fi
   end script
```

Comment: Where can I learn more about writing code like this? What language is it?

Comment: this is a simple shell . you can learn more about upstart from this link and add your code according to requirement . http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/